# Merge every last two lines in a 3-line row together

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I wanted to merge every line 2-3 together and keep line 1. Here is the example of my text

```
>chrX:147147161-147148161
ATGATGGTGATGTACAGATGGGTTTTTGG
TTATCTAATTCATGTGTTGGTCAGATCAA
>chrY:16119725-16120725
CAGCTTTGTTCCGTTGCTGGTGAGGAACT
GACTCCCTGGGTGTAGGACCCTCCGAGCC
```

What I want it to look like

```
>chrX:147147161-147148161
ATGATGGTGATGTACAGATGGGTTTTTGGTTATCTAATTCATGTGTTGGTCAGATCAA
>chrY:16119725-16120725
CAGCTTTGTTCCGTTGCTGGTGAGGAACTGACTCCCTGGGTGTAGGACCCTCCGAGCC
```

I have tried several ways but none has been working so far. Here is what I have been trying to do

```
> sed '/>$/,/>$/ {//b; N; s/\n//;}' file.txt
```

This command could not merge my lines. I also tried this before

```
> paste -d "" - - < txt.file .
```

This only merge my chr line and the sequence line, which was not what I wanted. Can someone give my some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with FASTA files and these can be processed with ease using awk. The following works for generic fasta files, with one or more lines per sequence.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";FS="\n";OFS=""}
    (FNR==1){next}
    {name=$1;seq=substr($0,index($0,FS));gsub(FS,OFS,seq)}
    {print RS name FS seq}' file.fasta
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- sequence lines do not contain (trailing) white space
- sequence lines do not end with a `\r` (windows/dos line ending)
- a sequence spans exactly 2 lines (not 1 line, not 3+ lines)
- NOTE: additional logic can be added to address any invalid assumptions

A couple variations on an `awk` idea:

```
awk '
(NR%3)==2 { line2=$0; next }
(NR%3)==0 { print line2 $0; next }
1
' file.txt

####################

awk '
(NR%3)==2 { line2=$0; next }
          { print line2 $0 }
(NR%3)==0 { line2="" }
' file.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
>chrX:147147161-147148161
ATGATGGTGATGTACAGATGGGTTTTTGGTTATCTAATTCATGTGTTGGTCAGATCAA
>chrY:16119725-16120725
CAGCTTTGTTCCGTTGCTGGTGAGGAACTGACTCCCTGGGTGTAGGACCCTCCGAGCC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    /^>/ {
          header=$0; lines=""; i=0
          while(i<2){
            getline
            lines=lines $0
            i++
          }
          printf "%s\n%s\n", header, lines
    }
' input

>chrX:147147161-147148161
ATGATGGTGATGTACAGATGGGTTTTTGGTTATCTAATTCATGTGTTGGTCAGATCAA
>chrY:16119725-16120725
CAGCTTTGTTCCGTTGCTGGTGAGGAACTGACTCCCTGGGTGTAGGACCCTCCGAGCC
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

With the `v` global command, something like:

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/^>/j' ,p Q | ed -s file.fasta
```

---

With the `g` global command, something like:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^[^>]/j' ,p Q | ed -s file.fasta
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.